# Multiple Recursive function calls in J

Tags: recursion, j

I am currently trying to write this function in J:
[image: T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\times T(n-i)]
(T(1)=1)

My code is:

```
ints=: }.&i.          NB. list from 1 to n-1
chs =: ints !/ [      NB. list of binomials
subi=: - ints         NB. list from n-1 to 1
T=: +/(($: @: subi) * chs) ^: (1&<)
```

the functions work as they should, but the recursive call fails because T is called with a list, which then tries to generate a list of ints on a list.

How do I solve this or how could the function be written otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general form for a recursive verb is:

```
T =: main_body`default_value  @. main_or_default_check
```

The default value and check are easy here:

```
default_value =: 1"_
main_or_default_check =: 1 = ]
```

binomial is also standard, we can write it as

```
binom =: 4 : '(!x)%((!y)*(!x-y))'
```

the form of main_body is `main_body =: sum binomial(n,i) * T n-i`. We can use a helper verb `f` for the inner part of sum, to make things clearer:

```
f =: 4 :'(x binom y) * T x - y'
```

or in tacit form: `f =: binom * [: T -`.

`n` is fixed for each iteration of sum, whereas `i` goes from `1` to `n-1` (`>:i.n-1`) so:

```
sum =: 3 :'+/(y&f)"0 >:i.y-1'
```

Putting the above together:

```
T =: 3 : '+/(y&f)"0 >:i.y-1'`(1"_)@.(1 = ])

T each >:i.8
┌─┬─┬─┬──┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┐
│1│2│9│52│375│3246│32781│378344│
└─┴─┴─┴──┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, `func"0 list`, which is like `list.map(func)` was what I was missing, now my original function also works: `T=: +/@(T"0@subi * chs) ^: (1&<)`!